How to create app with additional permissions (use case) in Facebook
I created an app on Facebook and added Facebook Login use case. Now I need to add user_link permissions. From what I understood to this end I need to add another use case but when I click Edit use cases I see only Run ads to promote your app use case. What should I change to be able to add user_link permission?

Don't think that's a different use case. Just ask for the permission via the code you are using to trigger login?

@C3roe I'm getting page with this test when with user_link: Invalid Scopes: user_link. This message is only shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

On App Review - Content we can read

To apply for permissions, visit the app review section and click requests. This will bring up a list of advanced permissions and features you can request for your app.

So, go to

Click Request Permissions or Features. Basically, it will send to Customize use case where you can choose a use case and there will be Add more to this use case, click it and choose Data for personalization. Now you can ask for additional permissions.

For this to work you may need to fill some fields in App settings.
Mind that one of requirements is Business verification and seems one can't pass it as a private person. See this reddit thread.
